# Ace Editor in JavaFX WebView Scrolling Issues (large step size)

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, ace-editor, javafx-webengine

I am working with ace Editor embedded in WebView in JavaFX, but facing a little issue here with scrolling.

The scrolling is not continuous, but rather it **jumps by large step size.**

If anyone has faced this before and fixed this? Any help would be appreciated.
(Following is the ace editor demo embedded in webview).

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AceEditorExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();

        webView.getEngine().load("https://ace.c9.io/demo/emmet.html");
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(webView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(webView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(webView, 0d);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(webView, 0d);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new AnchorPane(webView), 400, 300));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to get a smoother scroll is relatively easy:

First, you need to have a local copy of the html file. Download `emmet.html` and the required js files.

Edit the html file, and find the script that defines the `editor`:

```
<script>
...
require(["ace/ace", "ace/ext/emmet"], function(ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
    ...
}); 
</script>
```

Here you can adjust the speed of scrolling. This works fine for me:

```
<script>
...
require(["ace/ace", "ace/ext/emmet"], function(ace) {
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");

    // Adjust scrolling speed:
    editor.setScrollSpeed(0.05);
    ...
}); 
</script>
```

Now save the file.

Second part should be as simple as load the local `emmet.html`:

```
webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("emmet.html").toExternalForm());
```

but due to a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8136466) in JDK 8u60, until it's fixed you may need to use a workaround:

- use Dropbox or similar to host the html and js files, in order to have an online url.
- process a local string reading the html file (I'm not sure if this will work with the js required files).